# Expanding menu using images

Tags: css, menu, responsive-design

I wan't to make a special menu for the iPad version of my website.

It should work like this:
http://itu.dk/people/mbul/humlum/images/ipad_menu.png

Click on IMG 1 and the menu expands (to IMG 2) and the links gets visible. When you click outside IMG 2 it disappears along with the links so only IMG 1 is visible.

I've come this far but it doesn't really do the trick:

```
<div class="nav_mobile_container">      
<div class="nav_mobile_elements">
<div class="nav_mobile"></div>
</div>  
</div> 

div.nav_mobile_container{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    }

div.nav_mobile_elements{
    display: inline-block;
    }

div.nav_mobile_elements a{
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;}

div.nav_bookmark:hover{
    display: inline-block;
    }

.nav_mobile{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background-image:url('images/menu_small.png');
    display: inline-block;
    }

.nav_mobile:hover{
    width:496px;
    height:500px;
    background-image:url('images/menu_small_expanded.png');
    }
```

I would really appreciate a CSS solution on this if possible.

Thank you!

Comment: We would really appreciate a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) :)

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is

```
#nav_mobile:active {
    width:496px;
    height:500px;
    background-image:url('images/menu_small_expanded.png');
}
```

But that does not work on an ipad.
I recommend to use a bit of javascript.

Create an onclick event that displays a div with all the navigation information you need.
With jquery:

```
$("#small_navigation").click(function(){
$("#big_navigation").show();
});
```

The css:

```
#big_navigation {
display: none;
width: ...
height: ...
etc...
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you've got any questions just ask!

Answer (score 0):

You will need javascript for this. Using `jQuery`, this is how you could make it :

First, don't set an `:hover` in your CSS, but just make a class that you will add on `click` :

```
.nav_mobile.navopen {
    width:496px;
    height:500px;
    background-image:url('images/menu_small_expanded.png');    
}
```

And then a bit of `jQuery` to make it work :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // expend the menu on click
    $('.nav_mobile').on('click', function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).addClass('navopen');
    });
    // close menu on click outside the menu
    $('html').click(function() {
        $('.nav_mobile').removeClass('navopen');
    });
});
```

The **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CuE9v/)**

**Edit :** with pure javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
    var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('nav_mobile')[0];
    menu.onclick=function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        menu.className = "nav_mobile navopen";
    };
    var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    html.onclick=function(){
        menu.className = "nav_mobile";
    };
};
```